# Using a type from a List for excecution a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Using a type from a List for a generic method, like this

Preparing data:

```
     List<object> all = new List<object>();
     all.Add(new CustomClass());
     all.Add(new ...());
```

Excecution statements:

```
   foreach (Type item in all)
            {
                temp.GenerateDocument<typeof(item)>(item);
            }
```

This should excecute my statement with different types.

Comment: In my case I have not the given "typeName"(from your question), but a list of objects

Comment: Then use  `item.GetType()` to get the type.

Comment: ok, but i can not write `temp.GenerateDocument<item.GetType()>(item);` the compiles does not like it

Comment: No you have to use the method described in the linked answer.

Comment: Ok, I can not use `this`, because its a static method `generic.Invoke(this, null);`

Comment: To be honest, please show bit more effort by yourself. Read the second sentence in the linked answer.